# Reordering XAML code?

Tags: wpf, xaml

example I got this line:
notice how parameters how unordered

```
<Button  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="200,150,0,0" Width="189" Content="Boo" 
Style="{DynamicResource btnGrayDownWIthcon}" IsDefault="True" IsCancel="False"
Background="{DynamicResource ContractApprovedGreen}"
Height="53" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name ="btnPoo" />
```

its a mess

Id like it to be:

```
<Button Name ="btnPoo" Content="Boo" 

Background="{DynamicResource ContractApprovedGreen}"
Style="{DynamicResource btnGrayDownWIthcon}" 

HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
Margin="200,150,0,0" 
Width="189" 
Height="53"

IsDefault="True" 
IsCancel="False"
    />
```

is there any automatic tool that can reorder xaml parameters by priorities and groups?

Comment: I would check if ReSharper from Jetbrains can do this
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html

Comment: Styling or changing markup could reduce number of the parameters so that no reordering is needed at all, e.g. placing button in a Grid and setting its Grid.Row and Grid.Column allows to remove Margin, Width, Height and both alignments. Background can be moved to style (be aware of styles inheritance).

Comment: This is my pet peeve - layout that's applied explicitly to an element. In **rare** cases this is ok - but most of the time you want to pass the XAML to someone else to style... if they have to spend hours removing explicit values **which override all styles** from your layout then will get annoyed (I know I do!). Relative layout is also very important for when your application runs on different devices such as phones/tables. You can't guarantee the size - so your app needs to scale. It's not any harder to do this (in fact it's easier most of the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a Visual Studio extension called XAML Markup Styler which you can download and use for free from http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/. My team and I have been using this for months and it works great. It does groups/priorities reordering too. :)